# How to save Maps and lists in Cassandra with Ignite Cache

Tags: cassandra, apacheignite

Trying to use Ignite (2.15.0) as a cache layer with Cassandra as persistent storage. The application is developed using spring data and all required configurations were done using XML. On trying to save a data in table that has map<BigInteger,Long> and List error pops up saying codec not found for HeapByteBuffer. I understand I may need to write my own codec here but not sure how to register with Ignite configuration?? Any other options??

Struggling to find a way to register a codec with Cassandra when Cassandra configuration is defined in ignites XML configuration.